# unrecognized field in odoo tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10, odoo

I created a product class that has a One2many relation with Sell:

```
class comp_product(models.Model):
    _name = "comp.product"
    _description = "Product Description"

    name = fields.Char('Product Name')
    description = fields.Text('add description of your product here')
    sell_ids = fields.One2many('comp.sell', 'product_id', String = "Sells")
```

and the Sells Class:

```
class comp_sell(models.Model):
    _name="comp.sell"
    _description="Sells per Product"

    name = fields.Float('How many units did you sell?')
    date = fields.datetime.today()
    product_id = fields.Many2one('comp.product', String = "Product", required = True)
```

And inside my view I added this code:

```
<notebook string="Other Informations">
    <page string="Description"><field name="description" string="Description"/></page>
    <page string="Update Sells">
        <field name="sell_ids">
            <tree string="Sells" editable="bottom">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="date" readonly="1" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

It looks like odoo doesn't recognize the fields inside the tree. I got this error:

```
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `date` does not exist
```

Does anybody knows what the problem is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your field `date` definition, because
`fields.datetime.today` is [a function returning a string](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d76237e038ac379ae96e2c72848a013731c3de03/odoo/fields.py#L1484) and not an Odoo field type,
thus `date` is ignored by Odoo. You should write `date = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Date.context_today)`:

```
class comp_sell(models.Model):
    _name = 'comp.sell'
    _description = 'Sells per Product'

    name = fields.Float('How many units did you sell?')
    date = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Date.context_today)
    product_id = fields.Many2one('comp.product', string='Product', required=True)
```

Also note that the `string` parameter in your `product_id` field definition should be lowercase.

Comment: It works!! I got my tree view but the time and date are not updated, all the records I added had the same time: 01:00:00.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the field did not exist prior to adding it (it was declared incorrectly and not loaded), so Odoo wrote the same default value (today) for any records that existed in the table previously. You can use `fields.Datetime.now` if you want to include the current time in the default value of `date` as well.

Comment: Yes. This code worked for me:
`date = fields.Datetime(default=lambda self: fields.datetime.now())`